# Making Xcode not to show R.swift files

Tags: xcode, xcode9

I have Xcode 9 and I use the R.swift module in my project. The R generated files are huge and therefore each time I accidentally click on one or open one using the "open quickly" option, the whole program freezes for a minute and I can't do anything but wait.
This behaviour is a bit frustrating and interrupts the development process. Is there a way to make Xcode not to show any of the R generated files in the following places:

- The project navigator
- The find navigator
- The "open quickly" option (i.e, when you press Command+Shift+O keys)

Thanks.